# Send SignalR message to individual client when using integer identity User ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

In MVC 5 I'm using an integer as the Identity UserId. SignalR looks for a string to send to an individual Client. How can I fix this?

```
public void SendUnique(string message, string userID)
    {
        Clients.User(userID).send(message);
    }
```

The SignalR API expects a string as the userID, but my application uses integer Identity user id's.
How can I make SignalR accept an integer User ID?

Comment: Why don't you just do a `ToString()`?

Comment: Or parse the string to an integer...[How to convert string to integer in C#](//stackoverflow.com/q/2344411)

Comment: I've done this in the past where an individual user was connecting to provide them with a current status by passing around the SignalR `ConnectionId` from the `IHub.Context`. You could keep track of this when connecting and associate user Id with `ConnectionId`